# can i initiate an object of a class through a statement?

Tags: c++, initialization

As i understand we can initiate  an object s of class sample through a statement,

```
sample s=10;
```

Compiler  will treat the statement as `sample s(10)`. if there is a one argument constructor with in the class sample , the statement would work but if there is no one argument constructor then compiler will flash an error.

I want to know. can we initiate an object of class sample through a statement,

```
sample s=10,20;
```

this is shown in the following example:

```
class sample {
 private:
        int a,b;  
public:  
    sample(int i) {
        a=i;  
        b=i;  
    }

    sample(int i, int j) {
        a=i;  
        b=j;  
    }

    void display(){
        cout<<a<<endl<<b;  
    }  
};  

void main(){
        sample s = 10;  
        sample c = 10,20;  
        c.display();  
}
```

***Would the above program work?***

Comment: `sample s=10;` is actually the same as `sample s = sample(10);`, not `sample s(10);`

Answer (score 4):

```
sample c = 10,20;
```

This will not compiled. Note that `,` here is not operator but a declaration separator and expects something like `sample c = 10, d = 20`

```
sample c = (10,20);
```

`,` operator will be executed and 10 and 20 will be evaluated respectively with later as result. The statment is equivalent to sample `s(20);`

> Would the above program work?

It will not compile.

`sample c = (10,20)` will compile and run but would not call the constructor with 2 arguments as you might expect.

> can i initiate an object of a class through a statement?

Yes, use `sample c(10, 20)`

In C++11 onwards, a syntax like `sample c = {10, 20}` is possible using [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as constructor argument.

```
sample(std::initializer_list<int> l) : a(0), b(0) {
    if(l.size() > 2U) { /* throw */ }
    int i = 0;
    for(int x : l) {
        if(i == 0) { a = x; b = x; }
        else if(i == 1) b = x;
        ++i;
    }
}
...
sample c = {10,20};
```

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/dKx6Y3)

Comment: This syntax works for aggregates (which don't have an initializer_list constructor)

Comment: @MattMcNabb Thanks, I missed it completely. Edited the answer.

Comment: `sample` isn't an aggregate because it has user-defined constructors. I meant to say that as well as being possible for initializer_list constructors, it's also possible for aggregate initialization

Comment: Thanks. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special) was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are already using C++11, it can be achieved with:

```
auto c = sample(10,20)
```